# Write a program to validate phone number input

Tags: java

Write a program to validate a phone number inputs by the user in these
formats:

> 5149856586
>
> (514)985-6586
>
> 514-985-6586

The program should output `"Valid number"` if the 10 digits are in these three formats. Otherwise, it should output `"Invalid Number"`.

The program should keep asking the user to input the phone
number until the user types in `"exit"`.

This is what I have so far, however when I execute this code it doesn't print invalid or valid.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
package com.company;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class ValidatePhoneNumber2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int LenPhoneNumber = 15;


            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("ENTER PHONE NUMBER:");
            char CharPhoneNumber[] = kb.nextLine().toCharArray();
            boolean ValidPhoneNumber = false;
            LenPhoneNumber = CharPhoneNumber.length;
            boolean Validlen = false;
            int i = 0;
            int countnum = 0;
            char Numberp1 = '-';
            char Numberp2 = '(';
            char Numberp3 = ')';

         while (LenPhoneNumber > 2) {
            if ((LenPhoneNumber == 10) || (LenPhoneNumber == 12) || (LenPhoneNumber == 13)) {
                Validlen = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Phone Number Entered is NOT valid ;( ");
            }

            if (Validlen == true) {
                for (i = 0; i < LenPhoneNumber; i++) {
                    if (Character.isDigit(CharPhoneNumber[i])) {
                        countnum = countnum + 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (countnum != 10) {
                System.out.println("Phone Number Entered is NOT valid ;( ");
            }

            if ((Validlen == true) && (countnum == 10) && (LenPhoneNumber == 10)) {
                System.out.println("Phone Number Entered is valid");
            }

            if ((Validlen == true) && (countnum == 10) && (LenPhoneNumber == 12) &&
                    (CharPhoneNumber[4] == Numberp1) && (CharPhoneNumber[8] == Numberp1)) {
                System.out.println("Phone Number Entered is valid");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Phone Number Entered is NOT valid");
            }

            if ((Validlen == true) && (countnum == 10) && (LenPhoneNumber == 13) &&
                    (CharPhoneNumber[0] == Numberp2) && (CharPhoneNumber[4] == Numberp3) &&
                    (CharPhoneNumber[8] == Numberp1)) {
                System.out.println("Phone Number Entered is valid ;)");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Phone Number Entered is NOT valid ;(");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: And what's the problem with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a problem for which regular expressions are well suited.  Consider using the following regex pattern for validation:

```
\d{10}|\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{4}|\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}
```

Here is an example of how to use the pattern with `String#matches()`:

```
String number = "(514)985-6586";
String pattern = "\\d{10}|\\(\\d{3}\\)\\d{3}-\\d{4}|\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}";
if (number.matches(pattern)) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to combine 3 patterns with "|" for you specified three formats  and validate through Regular Expressions in java.

```
String pattern = "\\d{10}|(?:\\d{3}-){2}\\d{4}|\\(\\d{3}\\)\\d{3}-?\\d{4}";
 if (Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(yourString).matches()) {
    System.out.println("Valid");
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid");
}
```